# how is the syntax of using NOT EXISTS in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I got error message :

> ```
> Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS ChildCnt from tbl_user_master u WHERE u.sponsor_id = '145' AND u.user_type = ' at line 4 - Invalid query: select u.user_id,(SELECT COUNT(o.user_id) FROM tbl_user_master o WHERE o.sponsor_id = u.user_id AND o.user_type = 2 AND o.status =1 AND NOT EXISTS (
> ```

mysql code :

```
$user_tree = $this->getAllRec("u.user_id,(SELECT COUNT(o.user_id) FROM tbl_user_master o WHERE o.sponsor_id = u.user_id AND o.user_type = 2 AND o.status = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT p.user_id 
                  FROM tbl_flamingo_product_order p 
                  WHERE o.user_id = p.user_id AND p.status=3) AS ChildCnt",

                "tbl_user_master u",
                "WHERE u.sponsor_id = '".$user_id."' AND u.user_type = 2 AND u.status =1");
```

May you help me find out where is the syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

it is ok. I found it. 
just replace 
status=3)
to 
status=3))